# Generate a result set for every day using values for current day or values from most recent day

Tags: sql, t-sql

Using start and end dates, we need to select the column values for each day or use values from the most recent date for which data exists.

for example, using this sample data

```
create table #t1
(location char(2),
item varchar(6),
postdate date,
posttime time,
qoh int)

insert #t1 select 'FL', 'itemA', '1/1/2014', '0900', 10
insert #t1 select 'FL', 'itemA', '1/1/2014', '0100', 11
insert #t1 select 'NY', 'itemA', '1/1/2014', '1100', 50
insert #t1 select 'NY', 'itemA', '1/1/2014', '0900', 51;

insert #t1 select 'FL', 'itemB', '1/1/2014', '0900', 100
insert #t1 select 'FL', 'itemB', '1/1/2014', '0100', 101
insert #t1 select 'NY', 'itemB', '1/1/2014', '1100', 150
insert #t1 select 'NY', 'itemB', '1/1/2014', '0900', 151;

insert #t1 select 'FL', 'itemA', '1/5/2014', '0900', 510
insert #t1 select 'FL', 'itemA', '1/5/2014', '0100', 511
insert #t1 select 'NY', 'itemA', '1/5/2014', '1100', 550
insert #t1 select 'NY', 'itemA', '1/5/2014', '0900', 551;

insert #t1 select 'FL', 'itemB', '1/5/2014', '0900', 5100
insert #t1 select 'FL', 'itemB', '1/5/2014', '0100', 5101
insert #t1 select 'NY', 'itemB', '1/5/2014', '1100', 5150
insert #t1 select 'NY', 'itemB', '1/5/2014', '0900', 5151;
```

I want to select each location, item and the last balance for all dates between 1/1 and 1/6.  For dates without entries, such as 1/2, there aren't any records, so I want to use the values for last known day 1/1, and use this similar logic for all other dates.

my desired results are

```
date    Location    Item    OHB2
2014-01-01  FL  itemA   11
2014-01-01  FL  itemB   101
2014-01-01  NY  itemA   51
2014-01-01  NY  itemB   151
2014-01-02  FL  itemA   11
2014-01-02  FL  itemB   101
2014-01-02  NY  itemA   51
2014-01-02  NY  itemB   151
2014-01-03  FL  itemA   11
2014-01-03  FL  itemB   101
2014-01-03  NY  itemA   51
2014-01-03  NY  itemB   151
2014-01-04  FL  itemA   11
2014-01-04  FL  itemB   101
2014-01-04  NY  itemA   51
2014-01-04  NY  itemB   151
2014-01-05  FL  itemA   510
2014-01-05  FL  itemB   5100
2014-01-05  NY  itemA   550
2014-01-05  NY  itemB   5150
2014-01-06  FL  itemA   510
2014-01-06  FL  itemB   5100
2014-01-06  NY  itemA   550
2014-01-06  NY  itemB   5150
```

This is what I've tried so far, which works, until I start using larger date ranges.  It then begins to run very slowly in my actual database where there 1 million+ rows are involved.  When the SELECT TOP portion is commented out, it runs very quickly.

```
WITH dates AS
(
    SELECT CAST('1/1/2014' AS DATE) 'date', 
           1 AS RN
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, D.date), 
           1 AS RN
    FROM dates D
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, D.date) <= '1/6/2014'
)
SELECT dates.[date], 
       I.Location,
       I.Item,
(SELECT TOP 1 #t1.qoh FROM #t1
    WHERE #t1.location = I.Location
    AND #t1.item = I.Item
    AND #t1.postdate <= dates.[date]
    ORDER BY #t1.postdate DESC, #t1.posttime DESC) AS OHB2
FROM dates
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT 1 AS RN2,
#t1.location AS Location, 
#t1.item AS Item
FROM #t1
GROUP BY #t1.location, 
          #t1.item) I
ON dates.RN = I.RN2
ORDER BY dates.[date] ASC, I.Location ASC, I.Item ASC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your dates CTE.

```
;WITH dates AS
(
    SELECT CAST('1/1/2014' AS DATE) 'date', 
           1 AS RN
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, D.date), 
           1 AS RN
    FROM dates D
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, D.date) <= '1/6/2014'
)
SELECT d.[date], I.location, I.item, i.qoh
FROM dates d
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT location, item 
                FROM #t1) a
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
                FROM #t1 t 
                WHERE t.postdate <= d.date 
                    AND a.location = t.location 
                    AND a.item = t.item 
                ORDER BY t.postdate 
                DESC) i
ORDER BY i.postdate
```

Comment: This is fantastic Ennui! It is perfect application for CROSS JOIN AND CROSS APPLY.  My query time was cut in half when switching to this method.